# what is wrong with my Spring MVC 3.0 configuration?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, config

i am a newbie in the Java EE Spring MVC coding area. When i configured my first Spring MVC 3.0 site, i got a strange question that i have to manually type the MVC named url route to make it work.
The complete url route in my example is:
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/hello.jsp
i wanted to send a word to the controller and display it on the view.
But when i click return, the error page said:
HTTP Status 404 - /hello.do
type Status report

message /hello.do

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.85

So the url route was then: http://localhost:8080/hello.do
And i have to type the complete route :
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/hello.do to make it work.
i think there must be some errors in my web.xml and SpringMVC-servlet.xml configurations. i post all of my code below and welcome any suggestions.

web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

SpringMVC-servlet.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd    
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"> 
   
     <!-- 配置上传文件的参数 -->
     <bean id="multipartResolver"  
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="209715200" />     
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />  
        <property name="resolveLazily" value="true" />  
     </bean> 
     <!-- 配置Controller -->
     <bean name="/hello.do" class="com.yyy.controller.HelloController"></bean>
     <!-- 配置视图解析器 -->
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
     </bean>
        
</beans>
```

HelloController.java:

```js
package com.yyy.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController{
   
  
   protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
     HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String hello = request.getParameter("hello");
    System.out.println("------:" + hello);
    ModelAndView mav =  new ModelAndView("index");
    mav.addObject("helloworld", "hello    "+hello);
    return mav;
   }
  
}
```

hello.jsp

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="hello.do" method="post">
   hello:<input type="text" name="hello"/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the index.jsp:

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>index.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${helloworld} </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `<form action>` like below. This is a better approach.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hello.do">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. i add this : <form action="SpringMVC/hello.do"> and i got the error something like that "Status 404 Not Found ...  http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/SpringMVC/hello.do" Not Found", so that i delete the word "SpringMVC/" and then everything is correct. So strange! And my hello.jsp file remains the same. Since everything is OK, so thank you @Akshaya Jeevan for your suggestion.

Comment: i got that "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" is the absolute path, so

Comment: <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SpringMVC/hello.do"> would be better...

Comment: <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/SpringMVC/hello.do"> would be better...